# simulate data insertion in mysql and then run it in production

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have an **intranet application that replaces some excel files** and many times I have to do database update that are made of different queries (the following is based on the success of the previous).

> User posts data via a form and the application runs the queries. If
>   the process hangs somewhere in the middle of the queries chain data
>   will be corrupted and I have to manually fix them having a look at the
>   audit trail of all the transactions performed.

I have tried to secure all possible issues that came into my mind that can lead to an error in a query but I want to make this app bulletproof as much as I can.

I was thinking about a mechanism that on Submit runs the query chain in a test mode and then in case of no err runs it in real mode. I have a test db and a production one and I can run the first time everything in the test environment and then in the production one but the two db are aligned manually randomly and the test one can miss some prerequisites for this queries.

So, question is: **is there a mysql mechanism to run all the queries in a test mode and then replicate the process updating the db??**
My actual code (just an example of one of these chains):

```
$error = '';

foreach ($chiesto as $key=>$value){
    if($value[$key]!=''){
        //ho indicato la garanzia come da aggiungere
        try{
            $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO azioni_row SET
                       id_az = '$id_az',
                       id_cred = '$credito[$key]',
                       chiesto = '$chiesto[$key]',
                       ammesso = '$ammesso[$key]',
                       data_ammesso = '$data[$key]',
                       rango_ammesso = 'chirografario'
                       ");
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $error = 'Errore ad inserire le garanzie in azione: '.$e->getMessage();
        }

        foreach($credito_fl as $key1=>$credit_fl){
            if($error==''){
                if($credito[$key]==$credit_fl){
                    //ho trovato una delle previsioni di incasso di una garanzia che mi serve
                    try{
                        $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO incassi_prev SET
                                   id_cre = '$crediti_fl[$key1]',
                                   azione = '$id_az',
                                   data_prev = '$data_prev[$key1]',
                                   importo = '$fl[$key1]',
                                   perc = '$perc_fl[$key]'
                                   ");
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e){
                        $error = 'Errore ad inserire le previsioni di incasso: '.$e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example: assume that the first query runs ok and the second foreach loop hangs somewhere in the middle. I'll miss some entries and it will be a shot in the dark to find out what I have and what I miss (data recovery using audit trail data is made by hand and can be time consuming). Also corrupted data can lead to some reporting to be buggy just because of the missing data bringing some functionalities down while fixing.

> Please note that data sanitization in this case is done before this
>   actual code. User has just to check some data as to be inserted but
>   data are already in the db so I skipped the "prepare statement" part
>   of the PDO query but this is there where the user input something that
>   must be inserted/updated in the db.

Comment: run it all in a transaction? just rollback at the end of your test and things are mostly back to the way they were

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have two databases, `test_db` and `prod_db`. First run the query using `test_db`, then send the `USE prod_db` query and run it again.

Comment: @MarcB but how can I run all the queries in the same transaction? How can I transfer there the intermediate php logic I have (like the `if($credito[$key]==$credit_fl){`?

Comment: @barmar this is what I actually have but they may be not aligned...

Comment: @LelioFaieta You use `$pdo->startTransaction()` to start a transaction. Everything you do until `$pdo->commit()` will be in the same transaction.

Comment: great! Didn't know that. I thought I could declare transactions only in mysql directly directly. Will give it a try!

Comment: You could also do it in MySQL directly. `$pdo->query("BEGIN TRANSACTION");`

Comment: that's basically it. php has absolutely no knowledge of db-side transactions. all of the transaction 'state' is kept in the DB, not in php.

Comment: Yes. I got the point. Thanks for the hint!!! :)